# How do I render a PDF file from the URL in android using barteksc PDFView library?

Tags: java, android, pdf

I want to render a PDF file from the URL. The file is stored in my server. This is my code:

```
PDFView pdf = new PDFView(MainActivity.this,null); 
pdf.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
String pdfUrl = "https://....";
new Thread(() -> {
     try {
         URL url = new URL(pdfUrl);
         HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         InputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
         pdf.fromStream(stream)
             .onLoad(nbPages -> { layout.addView(pdf);})
             .onPageChange((page, pageCount) -> { })
             .load();
         connection.disconnect();
     } catch (IOException e) {  e.printStackTrace(); }
}).start();
```

Strangely, the `PDFView` doesn't render the file, the parent `layout` is completely blank. When I run the `pdfUrl` in my browser, it shows the PDF file. So my url is correct.

Then where does the problem lie? Why isn't the file rendering?